# How to customize search button in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, button

I'm trying to customize the search button from bootstrap. What I want is when the user clicked it the div will expand like [this](http://awwwards.com) search button. So how can I customize the current bootstrap button?

[This](http://www.bootply.com/Wzutc6hrIk) is my actual button.

Comment: Submit your code in Bootply.

Comment: Try with this code: [Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/expanding-search-button-in-css)

Comment: ok just how can i make it go upstair the other menu items ? i mean for dont make every button move to the left whenn the div expand